# how can I simplify this expression

Tags: java, boolean-expression

```
if (this.skills[i].isBasic() == true)
```

how to simplify this expression ?

Comment: it is already returning boolean , why to compare it , use directly the result for condition

Comment: Why does this question gets downvoted? It is clearly formulated. Yes it is simple, but If you are on that level it is difficult to search for that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(skills[i].isBasic()) {}
```

This is the simplest way.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (this.skills[i].isBasic() )
```

Answer (score 3):

Obviously `if(skills[i].isBasic())`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(this.skills[i].isBasic())
```

this is just an alternative with less characters.

Answer (score 0):

If this.skills[i].isBasic() returns boolean value, you can just

```
    if (skills[i].isBasic())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isBasic = this.skills[i].isBasic();
if(isBasic){
//Do something
}
```